# What is the URL I provide to docker or podman to pull down a GitLab registry image?

Tags: gitlab, docker-registry

When I am [at a repo's container registry](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/container_registry/29547), I can see this,

[image]

However it's not clear ohw that URL works, the URL provided is

> `gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/alpine-no-root`

But I can't run

```
podman pull gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/alpine-no-root
```

It asks me to choose between the docker.io or quay.io registry, GitLab isn't an option. Moreover, if I try, to add `gitlab.org/`, I get an error

```
$ podman pull "gitlab.org/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/alpine-no-root"
Trying to pull gitlab.org/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/alpine-no-root:latest...
Error: initializing image from source docker://gitlab.org/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/alpine-no-root:latest: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
```

And, if I try to specify `registry.gitlab.org` I get another -- different error -- and it can't find the repository,

```
$ podman pull "registry.gitlab.org/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/alpine-no-root"
Trying to pull registry.gitlab.org/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/alpine-no-root:latest...
Error: initializing source docker://registry.gitlab.org/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/alpine-no-root:latest: pinging container registry registry.gitlab.org: Get "https://registry.gitlab.org/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry.gitlab.org on 127.0.0.1:53: no such host
```

How do I pull this image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use

```
registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/alpine-no-root
```

- The project is `gitlab-org`
- The domain is `gitlab.com`
- The registry is at `registry.gitlab.com`

The [naming convention on the GitLab registry is](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/#naming-convention-for-your-container-images),

```
<registry URL>/<namespace>/<project>/<image>
```

So you want,

```
registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/alpine-no-root
```

---

## Easy way

Click the clipboard icon to copy the url,

[image: icon for copy]

You may think that copies the name, but it copies the full registry URL you want.